# Android Studio: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to implement the Swipe menu list view library by Baoyongzhang, but keep getting the following error message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/baoyz/swipemenulistview/SwipeMenu.class
```

My initial thought was this would be due to the dependencies so I added

```
 multiDexEnabled true
```

(Which didn't work, So I've tried a number of additional things such as excluding the support module:

```
 compile ('com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
  }
```

Still does not work... Also tried Cleaning, rebuilding etc.. These All succeed, but when I press the run app button, this is where the error appears.

Any help would be appreciated, here is my build.gradle app module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android.app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
}
```

Note: To set this up, I created a new package and copied across the required files, and then followed the step by step guide on the github page to implement this into my application.

Library:
https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView

Comment: switch to 'compileSdkVersion 25  buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"'  and 'com.android.support: set 25.1.0'

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Is it not possible to run on 23?

Comment: try to make you compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion using the same API Level. If you use API 23, then change to `compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"`

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך ok thanks, I'll give that a go now

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך No Luck :(, thanks for suggestion though

Comment: you didn't import SwipeMenuListView in your project, do you?

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך Yeah I've imported that inside the main activity java class

Comment: @Alex did you solved this yet ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Sadly not, I've left it for the time being while I work on another part of my application, but would love to get it fixed.